# Depth First Search on a tree with more than 2 child nodes

Tags: algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

I am trying to prepare for interviews and I ran into this problem:

Given a root of a tree structure. The method getChildren() returns Node[] array which has all the children of that parent. The question is to check if a given Node x exits in the tree. How would I go about doing this in both an iterative and a recursive manner? It would help of someone could provide the pseudo code for it. I understand that we can do a Depth First search but I am not sure how to do so for a tree in which each element can have any number of child nodes.

Comment: Review what depth first search is

Answer (score 2):

Your recursive approach might look like this

```
FUNCTION exists(Node target, Node root):

    Node[] children = root.getChildren()

    IF children NOT null:  //if there are children go on to visit each one
        FOR child IN children:
            IF exists(target,child):
                RETURN true
    ELSE: //the base case, when 'root' has no children check if it's the value
        RETURN root.value == target

    RETURN false //will only be reached from the first call to exists() if there hasn't been a match already
```

In Python this would look like:

```
def exists(target,root):
    if isinstance(root,list):
        for child in root:
            if exists(target,child):
                return True
    else:
        return target == root
    return False
```

Some examples:

```
print exists(2,[[[2]]])
print exists(2,[[1,4,5,[2]]])
print exists(2,[0,0,0,[0,[1,1,1]]])
>>> 
True
True
False
```

An iterative in python would be

```
def existsNR(value,root):
    visitstack = [child for child in root]
    while visitstack:
        node = visitstack.pop()
        if isinstance(node,list):
            visitstack += node
        else:
            if node == value:
                return True
    return False
```

The logic behind this is that you go over each of the inital children of 'root', for each child which has children you then push the children on to the stack and remove the 'parent' of those children (child). Checking these for children and adding them in a similar manner... Until you reach one which has no children at which point you check for equality.